# eclipse plugin maven generated jar does not contain classes

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho

I am trying to package a new eclipse plugin project to a legacy project that generate the zip and updatesite to install on eclipse. But when I install the plugin on a newly-fresh eclipse, I get the error "Plugin com.example was unable to load classes".
I looked inside the jar in zip file, and the jar does not contains any .class file. Just src with .java.

I am using the tycho maven plugin, to deal eclipse plugin dependencies with maven.

added to pom.xml:

```
    <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
```

added to parent's pom.xml:

```
<modules>
    <module>com.example</module>    
</modules>
```

Here is my build.properties

```
source.. = src/main/java/,\
src/main/resources
output.. = target/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
.,\
plugin.xml,\
icons/,\
META-INF/lib/commons-codec.jar,\
META-INF/lib/commons-io.jar,\
META-INF/lib/commons-logging.jar,\
META-INF/lib/fluent-hc.jar,\
META-INF/lib/httpclient-cache.jar,\
META-INF/lib/httpclient.jar,\
META-INF/lib/httpmime.jar,\
META-INF/lib/resteasy-jaxb-provider.jar,\
META-INF/lib/resteasy-jaxrs.jar,\
META-INF/lib/resteasy-multipart-provider.jar,\
META-INF/lib/scannotation.jar,\
OSGI-INF/l10n/bundle.properties,\
OSGI-INF/,\
OSGI-INF/l10n/
```

Comment: `build.properties` with Maven? Please post the `pom.xml`.

Comment: Tycho reads packaging information from the `build.properties`, so the content of this file is important. What was in fact missing is that Tycho and the packaging type `eclipse-plugin` is used.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that my source wasn't in src/main/java/ and src/main/resources. My classes are in src/.

I just changed the source to

```
source= src
```

Now is working :)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you have the external libs in a `/libs` directory instead of `/META-INF/libs` ?
Also, if you're using the maven project structure, aren't the generated classes in `/target/classes` instead of `/target` ?